# C# log into site by GET query plus CsQuery

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest, csquery

community! I need your help. I faced with the problem where I have to log into the site to parse some information. I can't find the information how I can log into the site by CsQuery, but I found information that I can to log into the site by WebClient or WebRequest and then parse using the CsQuery. But how I can union WebRequest and CsQuery ?

Additional information:

- Use GET query.
- Save cookies when I logged the first time.
- Login form is in the popup  (modal window)

Sorry if I duplicated, but I can't find the information that I needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: CsQuery is css selector, it has nothing to do with login. You need to use webclient

Comment: I know, but how I can union CsQuery with WebClient and to be logged on the site? I found the code that helps me to make the right GET query, but I can't be logged into the site. I mean that I sent GET and trying to get the page again, but it looks that I'm not logged into.

Comment: You can select the form with csquery, read the inputs and action of the form and then perform the actual request using webclient.